# Check duplicated data in a table before inserting a new row

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have table, USERS, with the following columns:
    user_id, user_name, user_uname, user_pass

I need to check if a user_name exists and return -2 and if user_uname exists return -3 
else insert and return the inserted id for the new row.

How can I do that in a query? If using function I need to pass query to function as parameter?

Is there any way to encrypt the function?

Comment: @user112819: Why you want to pass query in function as parameter,correct me if i am wrong

Comment: yes i needed to pass query to function as parameter because i generated query from code and i want any one can't change it if exist in function so i needed to pass it and as security

Comment: :Can you update your question with some dummy code ,so that we understand your requirement well?

Comment: and i need to go database once time

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth would you need to encrypt the function? Your application users should not have direct access to the database layer. If they do you need to change this.

Firstly, you need to create a [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datainte.htm#CNCPT1642) on the username. I, personally, would allow multiple identical usernames to exist but it's your call:

```
alter table your_table 
  add constraint ui_your_table_username 
      unique (username);
```

This will ensure that when you try to insert a duplicate an error gets raised.

Next, you need to create a function to insert the data. You can use the [RETURNING INTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604) syntax from the INSERT statement in order to get the new ID you're inserting. At the moment you're asking to return both -2 and -3 if the username already exists. I'm only going to pick one of these as both aren't possible.

```
create or replace function insert_new_user ( 
    Pusername in varchar2
  , Pother_value in varchar2 
    ) return number is

   l_user_id users.id%type;

begin

   insert into users (id, username, other_column)
   values (user_id_seq.nextval, Pusername, Pother_column)
   returning id into l_user_id;

   return l_user_id;

-- An exception is raised if the unique index is violated.
-- Catch this and use it to return the default error value.
exception when dup_val_on_index then
   return -2;

end;
/
```

I've assumed the following (you haven't provided that much information):

1. Your user ID column is a number.
2. You have a sequence in place.
3. Your users table is called USERS

Comment: There is no specific column @user1012819. The error will be raised if any unique or primary key constraint is violated. If your table has been constructed correctly you should only have two of these though. The PK is your ID and the unique index is USERNAME.

Comment: i needed -2 for first column and -3 for second if duplicated data to know what column is duplicate and give alert message for user

Answer (score 0):

U can wrap your functions using wrap utility.http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/wrap.htm

But as you are passing your code dynamically to the the function there shouldnt be any need to wrap your code

Answer (score 0):

dude i've try this by using  **triggers**.This code can do,when ever u perform insert operation on the table,it'll check whether that  table contain duplicates or not if yes then it'll raise exception and abort the operation.
trigger creation:

```
create or replace
trigger schema2.ins_tri
before insert  on schema2.users for each row
declare
  usr_ex exception;
  tmp number(30);
begin

    tmp:=schema2.ins_fun('schema2.users',:new.USER_NAME,:new.USER_UNAME );
    if(tmp!=0)
    then
    raise usr_ex;
    else 
      dbms_output.put_line('inserted successfullly');
    end if; 

exception
  when usr_ex then
      raise_application_error
            (-20001
             , 'there is some dupticate values in the table'
             , true); 
end;
```

return function:-

```
create or replace
function         ins_fun(table_name in varchar2,u_name varchar2,name_1 varchar2)return number 
is 
type col_1 is table of number;
c1 col_1;
type col_2 is table of  number;
c2 col_2;
type col_3 is table of  number;
c3 col_3;
begin

  select  tmp bulk collect into c1 from  (select count(*) tmp  from schema2.users u  group by (u.user_name))  where tmp>=2; 
   select  tmp bulk collect into c1 from  (select count(*) tmp  from schema2.users u where u.user_name=u_name  group by (u.user_name))  where tmp>=1;--check new insert value matches form the table
  dbms_output.put_line(c1.count||'c2 count');
  select * bulk collect into c3 from  (select count(*) tmp  from schema2.users u group by (u.user_uname))  where tmp>=2; 
   select * bulk collect into c3 from  (select count(*) tmp  from schema2.users u where u.user_uname=name_1 group by (u.user_uname))  where tmp>=1; 
    dbms_output.put_line(c3.count||'c3 count');
  if(c1.count>=1)
  then
     return -2;
  elsif(c3.count>=1)
  then
     return -3;
  else
     return 0;
  end if ;

end;
```

you can raise different exception if u want!based on return value